# WordPress page editing from back-end

Tags: html, wordpress, themes, backend, vs-web-site-project

How to edit a particular page from back-end ? From c-panel I have opened my WordPress folder but I can't find that particular page.  The page url is mysite.com/projects. But I can't find any a file projects.php in back-end.

Where is pages we create from dashboard located in WordPress folder? 
Wodpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/.... what is next?

The page I want to edit is a page created from dashboard. I want to change a single title from the page (all projects  to all products,as  required by the client ). I can't change it from dashboard. It appears default as 'all projects'.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- Open the page from dashboard and check the right bottom side for `template` option.
- If there is a template name then you can check from the WordPress folder via `ftp.open` all pages and find template name. Template name must be declared in top as a comment in pages.
- Usually the page you created in dashboard will be in WordPress folder under `/wp-content/themes/your_site/`.